# Как обновить или записать первую строку через Eloquent?

Tags: laravel

У меня в таблице может быть только одна строка, не более. В начальный момент времени может не быть ни одной строки. Там записывается значение **true** или **false** в столбце **show**. Мне нужно:

1. если записей нет, то создать запись, которая содержит **true**
   или **false**
2. если есть запись (двух записей быть не должно), то
       делаем апдейт все для того же столбца **show**.

Как это реализовать красиво? У меня есть решения, но они выглядят не очень. Сначала  определяю количество записей, если одна, то делаю апдейт. Если ни одной, то тогда добавляю. Но это все через **if**, конструкция получается громоздкая. И целых 2 запроса в БД. Уверен, можно сделать красивее.

Comment: ну так что? разобрались?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `updateOrCreate`

> You may also come across situations where you want to update an existing model or create a new model if none exists. Laravel provides an updateOrCreate method to do this in one step. Like the firstOrCreate method, updateOrCreate persists the model, so there's no need to call  save():

```
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```

[Ссылка](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) на документацию.